# jQuery event inside jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make it so when you click on an image loaded with jQuery it will trigger something, I decided to use the "onclick" event using html to run a jQuery script but there seems to be an error.

Error:

```
Unexpected token "/"
```

Code:

```
$("<img>").attr("src", item.preview.medium).attr("style", "margin-right:1%;margin-top:1%;").attr("onclick", 
    "$('#placeholder').html('<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
    style="float:left;margin-left:1%;margin-bottom:1%;" height="378" width="620" 
    id="live_embed_player_flash" 
    data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=' + item.channel.display_name + '&auto_play=false"
    bgcolor="#000000">
         <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
         <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
         <param name="allowNetworking" value="all" />
         <param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" />
         <param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=' + item.channel.display_name + '&auto_play=false&start_volume=25" />
     </object>')").appendTo("#content");
```

New Code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=path%20of%20exile&callback=?", function (data) {
    $.each(data.streams, function (index, item) {
                $("<img>").attr("src", item.preview.medium).attr("style", "margin-right:1%;margin-top:1%;").attr("id", "imgg").appendTo("#content");
                       $("#imgg").click(function() {
                       var obj=$( "<object></object>", 
                       { "style" : "float:left;margin-left:1%;margin-bottom:1%;",
                       "height": "378", "width": "320", "bgcolor": "#000000",
                       "id" : "live_embed_player_flash",
                       "data" : "http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=" + item.channel.display_name + "&auto_play=false" 
                       });
                       $('#placeholder').empty().append(obj);
                })
    });

});
</script>
```

Error:

http://gyazo.com/5cd42fd599822344b0a00c5f8f5e63ab.png

It only gets this error when I click on the image btw.

Comment: I've put the code on multiple lines and turned on syntax highlighting. This also shows where the code quoting breaks down :-)

Comment: Thanks man! I guess I should've done that D:

Answer (score 1):

Your code string has problematic quote management:

```
"$('#placeholder').html('<object type=" // being the string
application/x-shockwave-flash // not in the string, the "/" here being the unexpected token.
```

It would probably be much easier to not try and do this all in one line, and generate your object html block for your placeholder using a separate function - perhaps build it up with jQuery and then get the html string?

Comment: Ohh I see what you mean, so how would I actually do this? The single quotes would end the first html method's string.

Comment: @user3023566: I'd suggest not to use an HTML string to create the element. It's just too much. Instead, create the DOM elements directly and set their properties. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes

Comment: You could use \ to escape some of the quotes, but that is a bad way to do it. Building DOM elements as @Felix has suggested is the way forward

Comment: I don't fully understand, but what would be the code to add an attribute to the element, I gave it the id "imgg".

Comment: @user3023566: `var $object = $('<object />', {id: 'live_embed_player_flash', style: '...'})`. And then manipulate it further, like append the children to it, etc.

Comment: After I output it, what would be the alternative function to add an HTML attribute to it with this script?

Comment: @FelixKling you're not making much sense. I understand what you're saying but how does this help me with my issue? Like I already said what would be the alternative function, creating a variable and setting the style of it doesn't help me.

Comment: @user3023566 - http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jquery-insert-element-part1/ has a good tutorial on building with jQuery as well.

Comment: @user3023566: See, there is so much string and HTML stuff going on that I didn't even recognize that the second line is actually the content of an attribute value! Well, don't use inline event handlers. Bind the event handler with jQuery: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/. You are already in a JavaScript environment, there is no need to generate JavaScript.

Comment: Oh wow now I feel stupid why didn't I think of that. I could've just used a javascript event D: Thankyou!

Comment: [vogomatix's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20177975/836214) has a good start on your object html generation with jQuery, which is what Felix and I have been recommending

Answer (score 1):

```javascript
// this creates the object...

var obj=$( "<object></object>", 
   { "style" : "float:left;margin-left:1%;margin-bottom:1%;",
   "height": "378", "width": "320", "bgcolor": "#000000",
   "id" : "live_embed_player_flash",
   "data" : "http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=" + item.channel.display_name + "&auto_play=false" 
   });

// now you need to add the params to this
....
// finally put it in place
$('#placeholder').empty().append(obj);
```

Comment: How would I add the object though? Maybe if you add that to your code I'd have a better understanding as I'm still a bit jumbled about this. I know now that using a javascript click event would be easier but I am still missing something.

Comment: @user3023566: `$('#placeholder').empty().append(obj);`

Comment: @FelixKling thanks. Unfortunately I'm travelling around a lot and have work so I won't be able to complete it

Comment: Hmm...its returning some error. I'll post the code and error.